# Having `/favicon.ico` accessible on Heroku with asset_sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I'm having this little issue that is starting to really bother me.

My Rails app is on Heroku and is plugged to Bugsnag that tells me that some browser tries to access `/favicon.ico`. Unfortunately, my favicon is not under `/favicon.ico` as I specify on my HTML:

```
%link{ href: asset_path('favicon.ico'), rel: 'icon', type: 'image/ico' }
%link{ href: asset_path('favicon.png'), rel: 'apple-touch-icon' }
```

And as I am using asset_sync with S3, the href generated for the favicon links to S3 and not to `/favicon.ico` or `favicon.png` So I would like to make `/favicon.ico` accessible for those browsers that do not understand HTML.

Here is what I tried in vain:

- Add `favicon.ico` file in public folder on Heroku (by running `heroku run bash`and wget a favicon.ico)
- Try to add a route to `/favicon.ico` and [render the image via controller](http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/7-render-image-with-rails-controller).

That seems simple but I can't figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add shortcut to rel attribute

```
%link{ href: asset_path('favicon.ico'), rel: 'shortcut icon', type: 'image/ico' }
```

It could help to maintain versions of IE earlier than 9
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon